# Change order of event-handler-execution with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know there is this [repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/bind-first/) for binding an event handler as first to be executed. I would like to achieve the same with pure JavaScript, but I read [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) that it ain't possible to check for the event-listeners being attached to an element. If so, is there another way to do this (preferably cross-browser down to IE9)?

My usecase for this is to execute a event-handler before another one which I can't control as it is added by a JavaScript-framework. There might be better work-arounds for my specific case, but I would like to know, if there is a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, setTimeout(...,0) does the trick. There is also important if event is sync or async. [This article](http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth) could be helpful.

Comment: setTimeout does delay the function-execution, but the other way round is not possible. Thank you for the interesting link though!